# redis connection + singleton + node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am using redis to store sessions in my project.

In `app.js`

```
var client  = redis.createClient();

client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('could not establish a connection with redis. ' + err);
});
client.on('connect', function (err) {
  console.log('connected to redis successfully');
});
```

In my `routes.js` files i have to get all information from redis, so i am using the following:

```
var client = redis.createClient();

client.on('error', function(err){
  console.log('Something went wrong ', err)
});
```

But everytime its connecting to redis. How can i connect redis once in my `app.js` and use it everywhere. please suggest ideas. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
app.js

module.exports.client = client;

routes.js

var client = require("../app.js").client;
client.hgetall();
```

But i am receiving `error`

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hgetall' of undefined
```

Comment: export the `client ` from `app.js`.. then import the `client ` into `routes.js`

Comment: @Ritwick Dey thanks, could you please provide some examples

Comment: Sorry. I though it is a client application.

Comment: You have to manage session in that case

Comment: @Ritwick Dey Please see my edited post

Comment: Sorry for making confusion. Let me know you want `redis.createClient();`  one instance/request or  one instance/user or one instance in full life time of app

Comment: @Ritwick Dey  ` one instance in full life time of app` so that i can avoid unnecessary connections

Comment: Then it should work (my answer below)

Answer (score 2):

In `app.js`

```
var client  = redis.createClient();

client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('could not establish a connection with redis. ' + err);
});
client.on('connect', function (err) {
  console.log('connected to redis successfully');
});

module.exports = { client }
```

In `routes.js`

```
var { client } = require('./app');

client.on('error', function(err){
  console.log('Something went wrong ', err)
});
```

*(Assuming `app.js` and `routes.js` are in same level of directory)*

**EDIT: fixed few typo**

Answer (score 0):

app.js

```
    const redis = require('redis'),
redisClient = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1');
const http = require('http');

const REDIS_USER_DATA_INDEX = 2;

redisClient.select(REDIS_USER_DATA_INDEX);

module.exports.client = redisClient;
```

routes.js

```
    const app = require('./app');

app.client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('redis connected');
    console.log(`connected ${app.client.connected}`);
}).on('error', function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

I hope this will resolve your issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*A **singleton** is a class that allows only a single instance of itself to be created and gives access to that created instance*. In object-oriented programming, it is a  design pattern. The code snippets below can be considered an attempt to implement a singleton class in Node.js.

```
import { createClient } from "redis";
import logger from "./logger";
import "dotenv/config";

export type RedisClientType = ReturnType<typeof createClient>;

export class RedisInstance {
    private static instance: RedisInstance;
    private static CacheClient: RedisClientType;

    //Database Credentials
    private REDIS_URL: string = process.env.REDIS_URL!;
    private REDIS_USERNAME: string = process.env.REDIS_USERNAME!;
    private REDIS_PASSWORD: string = process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD!;
    private REDIS_PORT: string = process.env.REDIS_PORT!;
    private RedisClient = createClient({
        username: this.REDIS_USERNAME,
        password: this.REDIS_PASSWORD,
        socket: {
            host: this.REDIS_URL,
            port: Number(this.REDIS_PORT),
        },
    });

    // Constructor
    private constructor() {
        logger.warn(" New Redis Client Instance Created!!");
    }

    private async initialize() {
        try {
            if (
                !this.REDIS_URL ||
                !this.REDIS_USERNAME ||
                !this.REDIS_PASSWORD ||
                !this.REDIS_PORT
            ) {
                logger.error(" Redis ENV is not set!!");
            }

            RedisInstance.CacheClient = await this.RedisClient.connect();
            const clientId = await RedisInstance.CacheClient.sendCommand([
                "CLIENT",
                "ID",
            ]);
            logger.info(`✅ Connected to Redis with ID: ${clientId}`);
        } catch (err) {
            logger.error("❌ Could not connect to Redis\n%o", err);
            throw err;
        }
    }

    //Singleton Function Implement
    public static getInstance = async (): Promise<RedisInstance> => {
        if (!RedisInstance.instance) {
            RedisInstance.instance = new RedisInstance();
            await RedisInstance.instance.initialize();
        }
        logger.info(` Old Redis instance Called again :)`);
        return RedisInstance.instance;
    };

    //Usable Function Component to get client
    public getClient = async (): Promise<RedisClientType> => {
        return RedisInstance.CacheClient;
    };
}
```

Now you can use that instance by exporting anywhere in code. Just like below:

```
import { RedisInstance } from "./redis";

export const example = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const redisClient = await (await RedisInstance.getInstance()).getClient();
    
   // Implement your logic with the client

};
```

Every time the ***getInstance*** is called it will return you the already created instance. The ***getClient*** will help to get the client that is connected using the credentials.